# Family permit unmarried partner

Tags: visas, uk, family

I just got a 6 months EU family member visa to the UK. We will be going to the UK in October for a month, but my partner will leave early because he needs to go back to work. Will this affect me  when I want to apply for another visa in the future?

Comment: Why should it affect you if you obey all the rules of the visa? The immigration rules do not say if you travel into UK as a group/family unit, you have to leave together. Now if you were a minor and had a accompanied-minor visas, then you would have to travel with the person annotated on the visa.

Comment: @user56513 I believe that as a matter of law a family permit visitor has no legal basis for being present in the UK if the EEA family member leaves early. It is unlikely to cause problems for future visa applications, I think, but it is still cause for concern.  In other words, one of the "rules of the visa" is being with (or on your way to join) the relevant family member.

Comment: @phoog According to the rules: 
_The EEA citizen you’re joining must either:be in the UK already OR
be travelling with you to the UK within 6 months of the date of your application_. I interpret this as meaning you cannot continue to stay there more than six months after the partner leaves. Am I stretching it :) https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/eea-family-permit

Comment: @user56513 the thing is that the permit is misnamed. It does not authorize anything, but rather serves as evidence that the the person's rights under the Immigration (EEA) Regulations have been recognized by the home office. It's not even necessary to *have* the permit to remain in the UK under the regulations. But once the EEA principal leaves the UK, the non-EEA family member no longer has a right to remain under the regulations, and she or he also lacks leave to remain under the Immigration rules.

Comment: Thanks ,am a little bit worried or should i just apply for a standard Visa instead  and we dey cancel the EU family member permit Visa